# oracle pl sql actual date writing as in excel

Tags: plsql, sysdate

How to write actual date in oracle pl sql

EOMONTH(Today())?

I know that Today() fuction is SYSDATE, but will it give me the in last day of month format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `LAST_DAY` returns the last day of the month for the date that is passed as argument.

```
koen>SELECT last_day(sysdate) FROM dual;

   LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) 
____________________ 
31/03/22             

koen>
```